# Why when I execute Pascal program, a part of the information in the console-box gets deleted?

Tags: command, pascal, box, geany

I am using Geany to write a pascal program, but the thing is when i make a bi-dimensional array, and then i try to show it in a `writeln()` a part of what it should show in the box gets deleted.

I tried with erasing all the `clrscr` from the code, but it keeps happening and i don't know why, could be because there is to much information to show at once, but is necessary to show all the info from the bi-dimensional array.

```
for i := 0 to 4 do // Show results
    begin
        for j := 0 to 19 do
            begin
                writeln(biArray[i,j]);
            end;                        
    end;
```

when the program gets up to this part, all the information in the box-screen gets erased and even part of the information from the bi-dimensional array too.

Comment: Nothing in the code you've posted causes the behavior you describe. Can you provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem? (The code should be able to be copied, pasted, compiled and run to produce the same problem, and should contain the fewest lines of code that can do so.)

Comment: Perhaps you should try to format the output in 20 rows x 5 columns (or 5 rows x 20 columns? Anyway, follow the advice by @KenWhite

Comment: If you're printing a bi-directional array, shouldn't you use `write` rather than `writeln` within the inner loop so the array items are printed on a single line, and then write a newline just after the inner loop to move to the next line?

Comment: Could you share what the actual output is (and maybe how the expected one should look like)?

Answer (score 1):

Since you had clrscr's you are probably using unit crt. Remove it, and things will probably improve. Unit crt punts tries to put the terminal in raw mode, and probably confuses Geany's terminal emulation.

Comment: This looks more like a comment than an answer.

Comment: rephrased a bit

Answer (score 0):

adding to Marco's response, take into account you'll show 100 lines of output (That's hard to view). Try using a table-like view like this (Of course, you'll need CRT unit but it's a little fancier. In this example you'll need to adjust the terminal to show 100 or more chars in a single line):

```
for i := 0 to 4 do // Show results
    begin
    for j := 0 to 19 do
        begin
            GotoXY((j*5)+1,WhereY); //Move cursor 5 chars each time. If your numbers are small, try using 2, 3 or 4... You need +1 because first position is 1
            write(biArray[i,j]); //Write on the same line
        end;
    writeln; //To move cursor to next line                        
end;
```

Good luck!